# How to align addContentView at the screen's bottom in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to ask something about the `addContentView()` command.
I have created a custom view apparted from a `LinearLayout(fill parent, wrap content)` in vertical mode and some buttons.

My question: Is it possible to place my custom view at the bottom of the screen by using the `addContentView()` command?

I now use `addContentView()` but my custom view is placed at the top of my screen.
I have already tried to change the height of the custom view in fill parent but then I have a full screen custom view.

Answer (score 15):

Solution is to wrap your custom view in a RelativeLayout that fills whole screen and then add it with addContentView. For example to add a custom Button on the bottom of the screen:

```
// Fake empty container layout
RelativeLayout lContainerLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
lContainerLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT ));

// Custom view
Button mCustomView = new Button(this);
mCustomView.setText("Test");
LayoutParams lButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
lButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
mCustomView.setLayoutParams(lButtonParams);
lContainerLayout.addView(mCustomView);

// Adding full screen container
addContentView(lContainerLayout, new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT ) );
```

This should make it

Answer (score 2):

Try with the folowing code

```
LayoutParams lp =new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;
        addContentView(b, lp);
```

Using `RelativeLayout` also you can achieve same. You can add rule to set view at the bottom of parent layout.

Thanks

Comment: i tried to use 
LayoutParams lp =new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM; but nothing happened..That's why beacause the height of the layout is WRAP_CONTENT and the layout placed at the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your LinearLayout in a other Layout. I.e. a RelativeLayout, and add this with addContentView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yourLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

             <!-- Yout content -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Forgot to say that i dont use xml but i create my layout dynamically.
In your code i think you cant use layout_alignParentBottom="true" in 
LinearLayout but in RelativeLayout..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_height="360dip">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewHelp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/My_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="8px" android:text="Download this mp3 file"
        android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dip"  />
    <Button android:id="@+id/My_btn1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="this is button !"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```